# Angular Validation on Submit with A Dotted Function Name

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-validation

I am trying to call a 'custom validation directive' by watching the ngModel.

My submit function name is dotted.[sllr.save()]

```
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" placeholder="must be numeric" class="form-control" name="meterCount" ng-model="sllr.entity.MeterCount" is-number>
<div class="m-t-xs" ng-show="sllr.save.meterCount.$invalid && sllr.save.submitted">
    <small class="text-danger" ng-show="sllr.save.meterCount.$error.cvalid"></small>
</div>
```

How should I type this funtion name in ngShow?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I thought that I should use the value in ng-submit. But actually giving a name to form itself works.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" **name="seller_create"** ng-submit="sllr.save()">
```